# Error inserting in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm executing a stored procedure, but it always throws this error:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "OSFRK_OSUSR_ijq_BANK_ACCOUNT_OSUSR_IJQ_BANKA_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID". The
>   conflict occurred in database "BANCDEV", table
>   "dbo.OSUSR_IJQ_BANKA_CLIENT", column 'ID'.*

The table is empty, doesn't have any rows, what is the cause of it? If I do TOP 1 in the select of the insert the error still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key means that the key given must point to a valid record in the 'foreign' table, so if it's empty, that's a fail. Cannot create a record for a client that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to insert a row into a table with a foreign key constraint.  For example, if I had two tables employees and e_numbers.  e_numbers had only numbers, but employees had the number from e_numbers and the first and last name of the employee, additionally the foreign key for employees is the number from the e_numbers table..  I could not insert a row into employees without a corresponding row in e_numbers.  Look at what column is the foreign key and see what table it is talking about.  Make sure you have a row in that table before you run this insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

*The below is a guess based on the information you posted. In order for us to answer the question fully, you'll need to provide some more information - whatthe INSERT statement actually looks like, what the relationship between the tables is (get the table defintion/schemas) and so on.*

That error is likely being caused because a column on the table being inserted into (from the limited information posted, I will guess it's something like "BankAccount")  is defined as a foreign key to another table (again, guessing it's something like "BankClient") on the other table's "ID" column.

Effectively it's defining a parent-child relationship ("one to many") between BankClient and BankAccount. So a BankClient with a given ID can have many BankAccounts, each of which is tied to it's BankClient via the "ID" column. So I would expect that the BankAccount table has some column along the lines of "BankClientID" or something similar.

What this means is that in order to insert a record  into the "BankAccount" table, its"BankClientID" field must have a value and the value must exist in the "ID" column of a "BankClient" record.
Hope that helps.